# Printing of background #000000 with text #ffffff fades

Tags: css, printing, wkhtmltopdf, uicolor, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to generate a pdf which has

```
body{ 
  background:#000000;
  color:#ffffff
}
```

Everything looks fine on pdf digitally but on print black fades

I know pure black is not good for printing , so my question is

which black color hex code suits best for pritner?

Found this article useful but don't know how to use it in css. It also explains my problem
https://www.purebuttons.com/faq/achieve-true-rich-black-print

Comment: just reverse a colours. No one will print your PDF with solid background cause it's too expensive.

Comment: Its mandatory cost is not a matter , what matter is black color fades and looks like dull grey

Comment: The problem with printer settings. What printer you used?

Comment: @KaranGoyal _“Which black color hex code suits best for pritner?”_ — What makes you think that there is such a thing?

Comment: @user4642212 check this article and also a video behind it https://www.purebuttons.com/faq/achieve-true-rich-black-print

Comment: This is not a problem with css. As a variant you can download 1x1px black image and set background as repeatable image.

Comment: @demkovych i want this on A3 sheet and got printed from a high quality printing press , if i generate same with Photoshop everything looks fone but with css it gives dull shade

Comment: as a variant you can try: ```body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution this is because #000000 return rgba(0,0,0,100) which is true black and bad for printing as 100% pure black ink is not available and it also loads printer

What i did is i used #060808 it is called rich black color rgba(75,68,67,90) it makes print perfect and didn't loads up the printer